# AWS lambda function logs are not getting displayed in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have below setup which I am trying to run.

I have a python app which is running locally on my linux host. 
I am using boto3 to connect to AWS with my user secret key and secret key Id.
My user had full access to EC2, Cloudwatch, S3 and config

My application invokes a lamdbda function called mylambda.
The execution role for mylambda also has all the required permissions.

Now if i call my lambda function from aws console it works fine. I can see the logs of execution in cloudwatch. But if I do it from my linux box from my custom application, I dont see any execution logs, I am not getting error either.

is there anything I am missing ?

Any help is really appreciated.

I dont see it getting invoked. But surprisingly I am getting response as below.

`gaurav@random:~/lambda_s3$ python main.py
{u'Payload': <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f74cb7f5550>, u'ExecutedVersion': '$LATEST', 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '7417534c-6263-11e8-xxx-afab1667510a', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '7417534c-xxx-11e8-8a24-afab1667510a', 'content-length': '4', 'x-amz-executed-version': '$LATEST', 'x-amzn-trace-id': 'root=1-5b0bdc78-7559e68acd668476bxxxx754;sampled=0', 'x-amzn-remapped-content-length': '0', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'date': 'Mon, 28 May 2018 10:39:52 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/json'}}, u'StatusCode': 200}
{u'CreationDate': datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 27, 9, 50, 9, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'Name': 'bucketname'}
gaurav@random:~/lambda_s3$`

My sample app is as below

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import boto3
import json
import base64
d= {'key': 10, 'key2' : 20}
client = boto3.client('lambda')

response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='mylambda',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse',
    #LogType='None',
    ClientContext=base64.b64encode(b'{"custom":{"foo":"bar", \
                            "fuzzy":"wuzzy"}}').decode('utf-8'),
    Payload=json.dumps(d)
)
print response
```

Comment: Is it actually being invoked? Check the monitoring tab graphs. As a bare minimum you should always see the start and end statements in the logs if it was invoked.

Comment: I dont see its getting updated. I have added my sample code and output of the response that i get from the invocation call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you're actually invoking the Lambda correctly. Lambda error handling can be a bit tricky. Using boto3 the invoke method doesn't necessarily throw even if the invocation fails. You have to check the statusCode property in the response.

You mentioned that your user has full access to EC2, Cloudwatch, S3, and config. For your use case, you need to add `lambda:InvokeFunction` to your user's permissions.

Comment: Forgot to mention about LambdaFullAccess too.

Comment: StatusCode is coming as 200 which is success in http